# How to create a box with line and add icon on side

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive-design

I want to have a box with line on side as input and output. A line has add icon which should be clickable. How can i design such one so that add icon will be clickable? Should i use svg image for line and icon? what is the best way? I tried using css as i want it to be `responsive` but i had to use :before and :after and i can't make it clickable.

[image]

Comment: This is not possible using 2 pseudo elements.

Comment: What is the way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a responsive CSS solution using `flex`

```js
function addButtonClickHandler() {
  alert('Add button clicked!');
}

function deviceClickHandler() {
  alert('Device clicked!');
}

var addButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
var devices = document.querySelectorAll('.device');

addButtons.forEach(function(addButton) {
  addButton.addEventListener('click', addButtonClickHandler);
})

devices.forEach(function(device) {
  device.addEventListener('click', deviceClickHandler);
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.add {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.add::before {
  content: '+';
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.line {
  flex: 1;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto 3px;
}

.device {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="add"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <div class="device">
    Clickable device name
  </div>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="add"></span>
</div>
```